# How to get the python.exe location programmatically?

Tags: python

Basically I want to get a handle of the python interpreter so I can pass a script file to execute (from an external application).

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: how can this question, which was asked 1 year _before_ the question that it is supposed to be a duplicate of, be a duplicate of it? It's the other way around.

Comment: @mhawke The other had more views than this and was better worded. Hence I duped it in the reverse direction. TBH, Both of them does say the same thing, So we can even flag for merger.

Comment: @BhargavRao: yes, it is better written and the title is probably responsible for that. Also the accepted answer is better and (now) includes a link to the documentation, so overall I think you're right.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

This works in Linux & Windows:

**Python 3.x**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\path\to\python.exe
```

**Python 2.x**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Yep - >>> import sys | >>> print sys.executable | C:\Python25\pythonw.exe

Comment: I think in a py2exe compiled app, it would point to the executable for the app, and not the python.exe.  Someone would have to confirm though.

Comment: That only makes sense if you are already running the Python interpreter.  I think he's trying to find the location from outside of Python itself.

Comment: "programmatically" I think means from within the python interpretter.   At least, that's what it meant for me when I can searching for this answer :)

Comment: Also works on Windows. As for py2exe... there's no way guarantee that python is even installed, in that case. Why would someone bother using py2exe if they figured everyone running their program was going to have python already installed?

Comment: As mentioned below this does't work e.g. in an environment or if you have multiple python versions installed. Obviously here you want the python version currently in use.

Comment: It's a convenient way when you won't add the python.exe to the path and wanna call it again in execv or other.

Comment: Doesn't the 3.x one work for both?

Comment: confirmed also works on Mac

Answer (score 64):

sys.executable is not reliable if working in an embedded python environment. My suggestions is to deduce it from

```
import os
os.__file__
```

Comment: py_interpreter = os.path.join(os.__file__.split("lib/")[0],"bin","python"))

Comment: @Akelian You have one too many closing parentheses. Otherwise that's great!

Comment: Didn't work correctly for my system, my lib directory was "Lib" so lowercase "lib/" failed to split.

Comment: just noticed the / is \ on my system (Win10) too  Makes an os-agnostic version a little dicier.

Comment: Maybe rather,  `pathlib.Path(os.__file__).parents[2] / 'bin' / 'python'`

Comment: Can someone explain why it's not reliable in an embedded python environment?  Is that the counter-case the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) means when they say systems that "makes sense"?

Comment: @rth `os.__file__` does not work in a venv due to symlinks/hardlinks; it will return the base environment's path for `os.py` so probably need an if statement to check `sys.executable` first, and if it does not end in "`python`", fallback to `os.__file__`

Comment: I was able to leverage `sys.base_prefix` and `sys.prefix` for the base python installation and virtual environment, respectively.  This was convenient since I was already importing `sys`. More description in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.base_prefix).

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on how you installed python. Note that you can have multiple installs of python, I do on my machine. However, if you install via an msi of a version of python 2.2 or above, I believe it creates a registry key like so:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe
```

which gives this value on my machine:

```
C:\Python25\Python.exe
```

You just read the registry key to get the location.

However, you can install python via an xcopy like model that you can have in an arbitrary place, and you just have to know where it is installed.

Comment: If it is in App Paths you don't even need to know the location do you? ;)

Comment: Looking in the registry is not really much use, because you don't know if you are running the python that the one in the registry is talking about.