# What is Ruby's equivalent of Python's sys.executable?

Tags: ruby

In Python, you can do

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
```

to get at the executable's location. Can you do the same thing just using something built-in to Ruby? It can be a special variable, method, etc.

If there isn't, what is the cleanest, most reliable way of determining the ruby executable's location in a cross-platform way?

**Related**:

- [How to get the python.exe location programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this in IRB:

```
require 'rbconfig'

key_length = RbConfig::CONFIG.keys.max{ |a,b| a.length <=> b.length }.length
RbConfig::CONFIG.keys.sort_by{ |a| a.downcase }.each { |k| puts "%*s => %s" % [key_length, k, RbConfig::CONFIG[k]] }
```

It will output an "awesome print" style list of all the Ruby configuration info.

```
   ALLOCA => 
       AR => ar
     arch => x86_64-darwin10.5.0
ARCH_FLAG => 
  archdir => /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.5.0
 ARCHFILE => 
       AS => as
  ASFLAGS => 
 BASERUBY => ruby
   bindir => /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin
```

`bindir` is the path to the currently running Ruby interpreter. Above it in the list is `BASERUBY => ruby`.

```
RbConfig::CONFIG.values_at('bindir', 'BASERUBY').join('/')
=> "/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby"
```

Checking my work:

```
greg-mbp-wireless:~ greg$ which ruby
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

There's a lot more information than this so it's worth running the code I added above to see what's available.

Answer (score 2):

Linux-based systems are OK with

```
`whereis ruby`.split(" ")[1]
```

It will call `whereis ruby` and parse its' output for the second entry (first contains 'whereis:')

The more strict method is to call

```
puts `ls -al /proc/#{$$}/exe`.split(" ")[-1]
```

It will get the executable name for the current process (there is $$ variable and Process.pid method to obtain that) from /proc/*pid*/exe symlink information.

Comment: +1 to /proc/pid/exe. However I guess we have to craft a special cross-platform glue method to answer this question. I hope someone (matz?) would come out and say it right out that "There's no such thing built-in to ruby".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only *truly* reliable way is

```
 system("#{Gem.ruby} another_file.rb")
```

This works even for odd cases like jruby being run as a jar, etc.

Also see

```
 OS.ruby_bin
```

https://github.com/rdp/os

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is in RbConfig::CONFIG
I think RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir'] provides the directory where the executable is located, the rest is s (or should be) straight forward.

RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir']+'/ruby' should work, even in windows as the exe can be ommitted

Answer (score 0):

Works in a script, not from `irb`:

```
puts open($PROGRAM_NAME).readline.gsub /#! *([^ ]+).*/, '\1'
```

;-)

Comment: I know, also env isn't the interpreter. It is not supposed to be very serious anyway.

Comment: I got that from the smiley ;-)  Is there really no internal variable that tells us the path of the executable being run?  I had a quick look at my Ruby cookbook but couldn't find anything.