# DJANGO: executing other .py program from views.py

Tags: python, django

I've xmlparser.py. This .py parses a local XML file and then create/update objects from models SQLITE3 database.

This xmlparser.py file is in the same folder as views.py. Well, I wanna "execute" xmlparser.py (which update my db) and then get in views.py database objects updated for HttpResponse.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I guess whatever you do in `xmlparser.py` is done with classes and functions. you should be able to import it and use those methods in the current python file.

Comment: There's no error... the code.. A is just an example.
import xml.sax
from models import Actividad

    ...
            
    def characters (self, content):
    ...
            A = Actividad.objects.create(titulo = "hola2", tipo = "tipo", precio=2.3, fecha="2015-03-04", hora="19:23")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
    parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

    Handler = MyHandler()
    parser.setContentHandler(Handler)
    parser.parse('your.xml')

Answer (score 1):

In views.py:

```
import xmlparser
```

Then just use it as other python modules. E.g.

```
xmlparser.your_method
```

Comment: I've no method, I just wrote
    xmlparser

Inside xmlparser I have something like this
        A = Actividad.objects.create(titulo = "hola2", tipo = "tipo", precio=2.3, fecha="2015-03-04")

and makes no sense. If I write it in views.py directly it works, but it doesn't inside xmlparser. In views.py I have 
    import xmlparser

In xmlparser I have
    from models import Actividad

Comment: To execute xmlparser in views function you may move xmlparser.py statements in some function and later call it. Using subprocess is another option. Check [@Josep Valis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30356645/303182)

Comment: Django responses me this exception:

Comment: Django answered me this:
Exception value: 'module' object has no attribute 'process'

Answer (score 1):

You can execute anything on the OS with:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python","xmlparser.py"])
```

Also look at the second answer here:

[using python subprocess call to invoke python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152340/using-python-subprocess-call-to-invoke-python-script)

Comment: I think that is a Django issue

I've no method, I just wrote
    xmlparser

Inside xmlparser I have something like this
        A = Actividad.objects.create(titulo = "hola2", tipo = "tipo", precio=2.3, fecha="2015-03-04")

and makes no sense. If I write it in views.py directly it works, but it doesn't inside xmlparser. In views.py I have 
    import xmlparser

In xmlparser I have
    from models import Actividad