# Running two different python script with different path using batch script

Tags: python, batch-file

I need to execute two python script script1.py (path: dir1) and script2.py(path:dir2) in loop.In order to run this two script I need to give the python path. Earlier I used to manually set path and execute the script. Since I need to execute script in loop, How can i create a batch file that could execute one script and after its work is done execute another.
I am newbie with batch script.
Thanks

Comment: What operating system or shell are you using and what do you mean by "need to give the python path"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script (which runs for 10 times) for this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 10` ;
do
   echo "Running Script 1"
   python Script1.py <path as argument>;
   echo "script 1 completed"
   echo "Running Script 2"
   python Script2.py <path as argument>;
   echo "script 2 completed"
done
```

Please clarify if your need is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python script that calle the `subprocess.call()` method.
It takes a list of strings containing the commands to be called.
You then use that with a `try` loop to check if the first script executes without errors, and, if so, call the next (optionally with a `try` as well).

```
#batch.py
import subprocess
    try:
        subprocess.call(['python3','path/to/script1.py'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e) #alternatively add your logger here
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        subprocess.call(['python3','path/to/script2.py'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e) #alternatively add your logger here
        sys.exit(1)
```

you would then execute this using `python3 path/to/batch.py` from the CLI.

Take note that, if you're using python 2.7 (which you shouldnt unless absolutely necessary), you have to alter the code to call `python` instead of `python3`.

For more references and information on the `subprocess` module check out the python documentation and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152340/using-python-subprocess-call-to-invoke-python-script)