# How run python script with arguments via Python?

Tags: python, cmd

I have simple command and it's perfect work from cmd. But me need that I can run this using subprocess.call or subprocess.Popen function.

***cmd command***:

```
python3  <some directory>/tools/upload.py --chip esp8266 --port COM8 --baud 115200 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash 0x0 file.bin
```

***My try***

```
subprocess.call(["python",
                 "<some directory>/tools/upload.py",
                 "--chip esp8266",
                 "--port COM8",
                 "--baud 115200",
                 "--before default_reset",
                 "--after hard_reset",
                 "write_flash 0x0",
                 "file.bin"])
```

For example this provide Arduino Console:

```
python3 C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py --chip esp8266 --port COM8 --baud 115200 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash 0x0 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_424950/Esp8266-lwmqtt.ino.bin
```

And I can run this command from cmd and Makefile

Comment: What error or problem occurs with your `subprocess` call?

Comment: @FiddleStix it's not working if I add print("hello work") after processes, result while(true) wait))

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze “it's not working” is a *completely insufficient* error description.

Comment: @FiddleStix Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 54, in <module>
    cmdline = cmdline + [write_addr, binary]
NameError: name 'binary' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your `subprocess` command is that you are passing the arguments incorrectly. Those parts that are space-separated on the command line need to go into *separate items* in the argument list:

```
subprocess.call(["python",
                 "<some directory>/tools/upload.py",
                 "--chip", "esp8266",
                 "--port", "COM8",
                 "--baud", "115200",
                 "--before", "default_reset",
                 "--after", "hard_reset",
                 "write_flash", "0x0",
                 "file.bin"])
```

If that still doesn’t work you need to show us the exact error message you’re getting.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/ArduinoData/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 54, in <module>
    cmdline = cmdline + [write_addr, binary]
NameError: name 'binary' is not defined

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze This tells us that your other application has a bug that’s completely unrelated to your calling code: it’s trying to use an undefined variable `binary`. You need to fix your `upload.py`.

Comment: I didn't immediately notice a change in your version. It's work, for whitespace need new argument case.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be run using python3 ?
e.g.:

```
subprocess.call(["python3",
                 "<some directory>/tools/upload.py",
                 "--chip esp8266",
                 "--port COM8",
                 "--baud 115200",
                 "--before default_reset",
                 "--after hard_reset",
                 "write_flash 0x0",
                 "-file.bin"])
```

Make sure python3 is added to the Path, but as long as it work from cmd, you should be ok.
Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22258715/5498515.

Comment: I try repeat recommendation from this ticket, but it's not work for me. My python environment add to Path variable, it's work for Makefile, it's work for cmd, but not work from Python

Comment: If your call works from cmd, might as well try:
subprocess.run(["python3",
                 "<some directory>/tools/upload.py",
                 "--chip esp8266",
                 "--port COM8",
                 "--baud 115200",
                 "--before default_reset",
                 "--after hard_reset",
                 "write_flash 0x0",
                 "-file.bin"], shell=True
)

Please note the set of shell=True.