# How to run a python file while one python file is running

Tags: python, file-io

I have two files `main.py`& `test.py`
Suppose the main file `main.py` is running  and after a point of time I want to run `test.py`
I cannot use:
`import test` or `os.system("python test.py")` because this run python file in same terminal but I want to run the `test.py` in other terminal

So I mean to say in one terminal `main.py` is running after a point a new terminal opens and run `test.py`

Any solutions?
Thanks :D

Comment: you could use concurency

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to run a python script when some condition is fulfilled so I would recommend calling the "test.py" using a subprocess library  (bear in mind there are other methods) like this:

```
import subprocess
if(your_condition):
  subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py', testscript_arg1, testscript_val1,...])
```

as mentioned here: [Using a Python subprocess call to invoke a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152340/using-a-python-subprocess-call-to-invoke-a-python-script)

Comment: This will run in same terminal