# Can I find the path to the python executable from inside python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current python interpreter path from inside a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927633/how-to-get-current-python-interpreter-path-from-inside-a-python-script)

The title pretty much says it. I'd like to know which python executable is being used from inside python. Something like

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov  1 2011, 03:31:17)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print <insert the code I'm after here>
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
>>>
```

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print <insert the code I'm after here>
/usr/bin/python2.6
>>>
```

You get the picture

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/usr/bin/python
```

as described here: [How to get the python.exe location programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the bash `where` command?

Anyways, here is what you're looking for:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Comment: Maybe he needs the name of the executable of that particular instance, and it can be any program linked with Python's library.

Comment: Great! - Wait, why wasn't I up voted or ticket? o.O

Comment: its `which python` command not where !!!