# Spark can't import pip module after pip install

Tags: apache-spark, pip, boto

I've pip installed `boto3` on my local machine, and then I ran spark-submit in local mode while passing the path to the directory `boto3` is installed in. Leaving me with the following command:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages app.py
```

And then when `import boto3` in my `app.py`, it throws the dreaded `module not found` error.

Is this the correct way to add a pip-installed python dependency to a spark-submit job?

Comment: Do you have `boto3` installed to all the other nodes in the cluster, if any?

Comment: @cricket_007 there are no other nodes in the cluster. this is the single-node local mode. on a local desktop computer.

Comment: And you can run that file on its own outside of PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

The Python used by Spark versus the one that contains the python dependencies from pip_install is different.
In `.bash_profile`, set your `PYSPARK_PYTHON` path and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to the correct Python path that contains the pip_installs.

```
    export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7/:$PYTHONPATH$
    export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
    export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

If the Python on your shell contains all the pip_install programs, you can set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to that path. Find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/749769/5298703).