# Getting Python executable name in sys.argv[0] when running Python from within a bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I have a bash script which setups the environment for the application. At the last line of the bash script I call Python:

*app_start.sh*

```
exec $PROGRAM_NAME "$@"
```

where `$PROGRAM_NAME` is the path to Python, e.g. `/usr/bin/python`, so this is how I run Python:

```
./app_start.sh /usr/bin/python
```

Now, I need this path as program name, i.e. in `sys.argv[0]` but when I try to get `sys.argv`, it is empty. Only when I pass a Python script as argument, I can get that script name in `sys.argv`:

```
./app_start.sh /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py
```

and `sys.argv = ['/path/to/script.py']`.

My question is, how can I retrieve ALL arguments, i.e. starting with Python path, from `sys.argv`? I need `sys.argv[0]` to be `/usr/bin/python`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need the python that is being run, you can use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

Comment: Looks like it was previously answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically