# importing requests module throws error in FastAPI application

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi

I'm using Python3.8, creating a FastAPI application and trying to import requests module. This throws error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"
However, in the Python terminal, import requests works perfectly.
What could possibly be causing this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Often the problem are the settings and environment variable of python executed by web server. On terminal you use your python and settings. Web server will start python from a different location/different user/etc.

Comment: You're probably not running the same environment in both cases. Check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically if it's the same executable and which one is missing requests (so that you can add it on).

Comment: are you using same python for both of thing ?

Comment: On checking I found there was some environment issue and other different python versions were being used. Thanks for help !